# PHP Convert GD Image to CSS Code for CAPTCHA

Tags: php, css, gd, captcha

For generating captchas which would be difficult to be cracked by a machine, I plan to convert images of text (B&W only) into CSS code to be displayed to the user.

So there are 2 aspects to this question:

1. Is this a good idea to make the captcha difficult to be read by a machine?
2. If so, what would be the best way of converting the GD image to CSS?

I plan to loop through all pixels in the image, check if they are black, and if so then write the pixel in CSS. But I don't know how to write black pixels in CSS (my CSS skills are lacking.) So for my second question, I would like to know how to write black pixels in CSS. Unless someone has a better idea for generating the CSS code, or if there exists a tool to do this already.

Please note that I am building my own CAPTCHA system, as I will be using the entered input to convert images of text into text (just like is done with the ReCAPTCHA system) except for my own purposes. So I must build the CAPTCHA system myself.

Comment: Why do you think this would help at all? It's trivial to render html/css back to an image which can be fed to captcha cracking tools. At most you'll just have annoyed users with older browsers who mis-render your CSS, and added a useless "security" measure that captcha crackers will just laugh at.

Comment: I thought it might put-off the larger percentage of captcha crackers, as they're probably not made to process CSS-drawn images. But I don't know whether this is the case, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: That's the point, though. It's easy to convert css back to a plain image and then standard capthca crackers get to work on it. all you've done is added a minor extra step to the process

Comment: OK, point taken... I would still like to pull some kind of trick, just something different to what is already done, as I don't expect someone to develop a captcha cracking tool specifically for my web site. Can you suggest anything?

Comment: CSS-ing an image would be massive bloat. Even a simple `<span class="black"></span>` changes your 1 byte pixel into 28 bytes of text. A simple 200x100 captcha image is around 10k as a .gif, and you'd be turning it into 527kbytes of html, plus the .css definitions. MASSIVE bloat.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no idea in converting the image to CSS. It just adds lots of extra overhead and creates a gigantic CSS mess, whilst not adding any real value. Security through obfuscation is bad - especially here.

Besides - what makes you think the CAPTCHA cracking software wouldn't just take a screenshot of your CSS mess and voilà: have your CAPTCHA as an image? Don't do it.

If you just focus on making your CAPTCHA text complex, you won't have a problem. Or you could just do as most people do - use [reCAPTCHA](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Comment: I'd rather focus on confusing the crackers... since this system will only be used on one site, if I do something different to others, then the cracking tools will not adapt to it, seeing as it is only 1 site.

Comment: Yes, and then that will work until some other sites get the same idea, and suddenly the cracking tools have adapted, and you'll have to obfuscate your CAPTCHA even more every few months.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
// generate the image $img
function img2data($img) {return "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($img)."\" />";}
ob_start("img2data");
imagepng($img);
ob_end_flush();
```

This will output the image data directly in the HTML file, and it will show up in most browsers (maybe not IE7).

Comment: He doesn't just want to output the image as base64, he wants to completely get rid of the `img` tag and draw the image using CSS.

Comment: Then just shove that `data` url in a CSS `background-image: url(...)`

Comment: I was hoping to force the cracking tools to have to render the image in a way that they do not support, whereas it is supported by browsers. Which is why I was planning on not using an image at all, but making it CSS code (assuming captcha cracking tools can't read CSS, of which I'm unsure.)

Comment: a background image is still an image